# ipV6 в docker-контейнере

Tags: docker, docker-compose, php-fpm, ipv6

Доброго времени суток.

Есть набор докеровских контейнеров (nginx, php-fpm, mysql, elasticsearch).
Контейнеры поднимаются пачкой с помощью docker-compose.
Крутятся контейнеры на vds (ubuntu), которые "из коробки" про ipV6 и слышать не слышали.
Мне ipV6 без надобности, и настраивать его на всех инстансах совсем не хочется.
Однако при выполнении `docker compose -up` контейнер php-fpm стартовать не хочет.
`docker compose -ps` выводит:

```
     Name                   Command                State          Ports       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_db_1      docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up        3306/tcp          
docker_elk_1     /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c ...   Up        0.0.0.0:81->80/tcp
docker_nginx_1   nginx                            Exit 1                      
docker_php_1     docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Exit 78
```

Если ввести  `docker-compose up --force-recreate`, то можно разглядеть такую ошибку:

```
php_1    | [02-Dec-2017 17:19:46] ERROR: failed to create new listening socket: socket(): Address family not supported by protocol (97)
php_1    | [02-Dec-2017 17:19:46] ERROR: failed to create new listening socket: socket(): Address family not supported by protocol (97)
php_1    | [02-Dec-2017 17:19:46] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
php_1    | [02-Dec-2017 17:19:46] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php:9000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:1
docker_nginx_1 exited with code 1
docker_php_1 exited with code 78
```

Если я ничего не путаю, то image php-fpm настойчиво хочет ipV6 на хосте (вне контейнера).
Погуглив, я узнал, что если запускать контейнеры по одному, то можно добавлять параметр `-ipv6=false`, и это вроде как должно помочь. А как быть в случае с docker compose?